# Measuring performance of CouchDb replication

Tags: performance, couchdb, replication

I have several PCs in the network with application that uses CouchDB. CouchDb is configured to replicate data with CouchDb instance on all other nodes. I would like to measure a performance of data replication between the nodes. I tried to find if CouchDb exposes some data about the time spend replicating data, but I didn't find anything helpful except the endpoint `_scheduler/jobs` that can show information about how many documents waits for replicating and a sequence number.

My current idea is a very naive script that will query each CouchDb instance `_scheduler/jobs` edpoint frequently and based on numbers returned in `changes_pending` and `docs_written` fields I can somehow get some approximate estimate how long it takes to replicate data. This is, however, inaccurate and take me a moment to setup. Maybe you know some easier ways/tools that can help me?

Questions:

Are there any way to fetch information about time that replication of documents took in CouchDb?

Also, maybe you know some tools that can help me with measuring performance of CouchDb replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a performance improvement for document replication in the 3.3.0 release. The [corresponding pull requests](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/4308#issuecomment-1353820482) also documents how the replication performance was tested.

If you want to test replication performance yourself, I suggest you follow their setup using [couchdyno](https://github.com/cloudant-labs/couchdyno).